# How to identify the contentsGravity property I am changing?

Tags: ios, swift

Whenever I navigate to a particular screen in my app I see this message show up in the debug console.

```
CATransformLayer: changing property contentsGravity in transform-only layer, will have no effect.
```

These are the contents of the screen.

```
---- Safe Area
    ---- UIScrollView
        ---- UIView
        -------- UILabel
        -------- UIButton
        ---- UITableView
        -------- UITableViewCell
        ---- UIView
        -------- UIButton
        -------- UIButton
```

Is UIScrollView the one that's causing this warning message? Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Thanks.